# Increase depth percept of upside-down cup

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to obtain a top view of a upside-down cup, with the camera displaced at an angle from the centre of the cup. However, the depth percept looks weak. I'm not able to tell that the base of the cup is nearer to me than the rim. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Top view of upside-down cup]

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of your settings or upload your .blend? There a several things which could be going on here, and there's no way to tell which without more information. (For instance, are you using an orthographic camera? Are you using a shadeless material? is AO enabled? etc.)

Comment: A screenshot of the material you use would be helpful. Also an overview of the scene. What lights do you have?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your model geometry is good (I can't really tell from the screenshot), it becomes mainly a lighting, material and environment problem.

**Lighting:**
If you are going for a photo-realistic look, use Cycles for rendering. It will handle lights and shadows in a more intuitive way.

**Material:**
Is it suppose to be a styrofoam cup? A porcelain cup? Glass? Set up the material for the cup accordingly. Styrofoam would be almost all diffuse, with a Sub-Surface Scatter component. Porcelain would be diffused white, with an added layer of highly glossy top coat. Glass would be, well, the Glass material node.

**Environment:**
If the cup material is reflective at all, you will need to set up the environment so that there is something to reflect off. After all, a mirror ball in a perfectly grey world will only look grey.  Multiple Plane Emitters is a good starting point, they can mimic lights shining through a windows.